# PHP email attachment delivered in encrypted format

Tags: php, email, attachment, encryption

Im trying to trigger a form with an attachment to an email. but for some reason , the attachment, the attachment is delivered in encrypted format. Can somebody help me please....
The requirement is to fill the form along with the attachament and all the details needs to be delivered to the email id without any issues...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


// Obtain file upload vars
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
   $type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
   $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
   $size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];


$name = trim($_POST['name']); 
$age = trim($_POST['age']);
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$occupation = trim($_POST['occupation']);
$address = trim($_POST['address']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$hphone = trim($_POST['hphone']);
$cphone = trim($_POST['cphone']);
$treatment = trim($_POST['treatment']);
$symptom = trim($_POST['symptom']);
$thistory = trim($_POST['thistory']);
$currmedic = trim($_POST['currmedic']);
$otherprobs = trim($_POST['otherprobs']);
$contactmode = trim($_POST['contactmode']);
$contactinfo = trim($_POST['contactinfo']);
$agree = $_POST['agree'];

$subject = "Request for Consultation from " .$name;  

$isError = "N";

if($name == "") {
    $nameErrMsg = "Enter your name.";
    $nameErr = "1" ;
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($age == "") {
    $ageErrMsg = "Enter your age.";
    $ageErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y"; 
}

if(!isset($sex))
{
    $sexErrMsg = "Select your Gender.";
    $sexErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($address == "") {
    $addressErrMsg = "Enter your Address.";
    $addressErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($email == "") {
    $emailErrMsg = "Enter your Email.";
    $emailErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
} //check for valid email
elseif(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)) {
    $emailErrMsg = 'You did not enter a valid Email.';
    $emailErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($cphone == "") {
    $cphoneErrMsg = "Enter your Cell Phone.";
    $cphoneErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($treatment == "") {
    $treatmentErrMsg = "Enter your required Treatment.";
    $treatmentErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($symptom == "") {
    $symptomErrMsg = "Enter the Symtoms.";
    $symptomErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($thistory == "") {
    $thistoryErrMsg = "Enter Treatment History.";
    $thistoryErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if($contactinfo == ""){
    $contactinfoErrMsg = "Enter Contact Info.";
    $contactinfoErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}

if(!isset($agree))
{
    $agreeErrMsg = "Select for Agree/Disagree to use your medical information in case studies.";
    $agreeErr = "1";
    $isError = "Y";
}


if($isError == "N")
{
$message = "
Name : $name <br />
Age : $age <br />
Sex : $sex <br />
Occupation : $occupation <br />
Address : $address <br />
Email : $email <br />
Home Phone : $hphone <br />
Cell Phone : $cphone <br />
Treatment For : $treatment <br /> 
Symptoms : $symptom  <br />
Treatment History : $thistory <br />
Current Medications : $currmedic <br />
List out any other associated conditions or health problems that your suffering with : $otherprobs <br />
Preferred mode of Contact : $contactmode <br />
Contact Info : $contactinfo <br />
Agree to use your medical information in case studies : $agree 
";
    $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
    $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
    fclose($file);
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    //$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
        // "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
      //   "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
       //  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $message = "\n" .
         //"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
         //"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";


    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $message .= //"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .

         "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
         "File Name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
         //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
         //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
         //"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n" ;

//if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) 
//{

//}

$to = "anand.pikay@gmail.com";
$headers = 'From: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .    
            'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
            'data: '.$data.'' . "\r\n" .    


    enter code here

    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if($send_email)
{ 
    $msg= "Your message sent successfully.";
    $name = ""; 
    $age = "";
    $sex = "";
    $occupation = "";
    $address = "";
    $email = "";
    $hphone = "";
    $cphone = "";
    $treatment = "";
    $symptom = "";
    $thistory = "";
    $currmedic = "";
    $otherprobs = "";
    $contactmode = "";
    $contactinfo = "";
    $agree = "";
}
else
{
    $errorMsg = "Error in sending email!!!";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You commented out `//"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"`. How is the receiving party ever to know how to decode it? Also, just using a proven package like `PHPMailer` saves you a lot of time & headaches.